# Ecmascript function parameter with enum value

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have an `enum` value of parameter in Ecmascript method?

For example for this case

```
export const testFunc = (param1) => {

};
```

For example, `param` can only take values of `"val1","val2","val3"`

```
export const testFunc = (param = {"val1","val2","val3"}) =>{

};
```

Comment: What is "Ecmascript method"? What you've shown is not a method but a function and it might also be TypeScript. Also, what do you mean by "enum"? JavaScript (which implements the ECMAScript specs) does not have enums. TypeScript does.

Comment: why you tag with `typescript`?

Comment: @VLAZ - Looks like a function with a default parameter value to me. I don't see any types in the above, so I don't think it's TypeScript.

Comment: Mahdi, as [Snow says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551659/157247), JavaScript doesn't have enums. [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) does ([details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)), so if you want enums (and various other features), you might consider using TypeScript, which compiles to JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That was the best advice thank you

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that was going to be my next question - the whole premise of the question seems to be to limit the types yet the function just had default parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no such thing as an enum in JS, but you could just check to see if the parameter is one of the allowed values:

```
export const testFunc = (param) =>{
  if (!["val1","val2","val3"].includes(param)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid param passed');
  }
  // rest of function
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Snow says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551659/157247), JavaScript doesn't have enums. [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) does ([details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)), so if you want enums (and various other features), you might consider using TypeScript, which compiles to JavaScript.

If you don't want to go that route, you can always define an enum-like object:

```
const TheEnum = {
    val1: 0,
    val2: 1,
    val3: 2,
    0: "val1",
    1: "val2",
    2: "val3",
    valid(value) {
        return typeof param === "number" && !!TheEnum[param];
    }
};
```

...and then validate the value you receive:

```
export const testFunc = (param) => {
    if (!TheEnum.valid(param)) {
        throw new Error("'param' must be a TheEnum value");
    }
    // ...
};
```

Note that that example "enum" has mappings both from symbolic names (`val1`, etc.0 to the values and from values to symbolic names. They do the in TypeScript, too; it's handy for when you want to show the name `"val1"` instead of the value `0` in messages, etc.